# Coloring a stacked bar plot in ggplot: what if my fill variable is comprised of several columns?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm quite new to ggplot, and I'm trying to create faceted stacked bar plots. I'm looking at the relative abundances of different strains of bacteria over several time points. Here is a simplified version of my data:

```
ID  Tmpt    Rep B1  B2  B3
A1  1       1   .2  .4  .4
A2  1       2   .1  .4  .5
A3  2       1   .2  .45 .35
A4  2       2   .2  .3  .5
A5  3       1   .15 .5  .35
A6  3       2   .2  .5  .3
```

My actual data has more timepoints (Tmpt), reps, and strains of bacteria (variables B1-B3), but this is the same format. The ID is just an arbitrary label for the sample, and the values in B1 represent what percentage of the dish is covered in bacteria B1 (likewise for B2 and B3).

I would like to make faceted stacked bar plots (faceted by rep), where each stacked bar plot has one bar per time point (so in this example, there would be 2 facets,each with 3 bars). I want each bar to be colored based on the percentage cover by B1, B2, and B3 (such that there would be 3 colors, one for each strain of bacteria). I've used `geom_bar()` before and I think I could figure out how to make the faceted bar plots, but I don't know how to color it. All of the examples I have seen of `aes(fill = mycondition)` in ggplot have all of the categories in a single column in the dataset, rather than as multiple columns. Is there a way to do this without completely reformatting my data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `ggplot` works best if each item in a plot represents exactly one data item. Make yourself familiar with the `reshape2` or `reshape` packages, data reformatting will be no issue then.

```
library(reshape2)
data.m <- melt(data, id.vars=c("ID", "Tmpt", "Rep"))
```

You should be able to use `data.m` directly for plotting the data in the way you need:

```
ggplot(data.m, aes(color=variable)) + facet_wrap(~Rep) + geom_bar(...)
```

See also the following slightly related question: [Repeat values to multiple plots when faceting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17813610/946850)

Comment: Ok, that definitely got me closer! I've used melt() before but I'd never specified multiple ID variables. So I tried running your code (had to add an x value in aes) `ggplot(data.m, aes(x = Tmpt, color=variable)) + facet_wrap(~Rep) + geom_bar(...)`, and I got the correct number of bars with the right number of facets, but all of the bars were divided evenly between the three colors...

Comment: All right, got it: `ggplot(tm, aes(x = Tmpt, y = value, fill = variable)) + facet_wrap(~Rep) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')`. Thanks for your help!