# Repeat specific value (row) in each facet using facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to make a plot with the values in 24h and 48h for all the different rows. The plot should be facet_grid where the facets are the IDs.
My problem: I need to have the row `Control` plottet together with each ID in all the facets. Is there a easy way to achive this without reformatting the input table?

```
ID          24h     48h
mir-21-3p   7122.67 8947.67
mir-135b-5p 7093    9288.67
mir-584-5p  7227.33 8406.67
mir-7974    7369.67 8879.33
mir-183-3p  7493    7915
mir-182-5p  7471    8797.67
mir-183-5p  7349.67 7542.67
mir-21-5p   7261.67 9221.33
mir-31-5p   6573.67 7575.33
mir-301b-3p 6950.33 8348.67
mir-92a-1-5p    7187.67 8645
mir-7-5p    7055.67 9535.67
mir-25-5p   7330.67 8636.67
mir-3176    7079    7385
mir-244-5p  7698    8932.33
mir-18a-3p  7177.33 8620.33
mir-2467-5p 6831    7662.67
mir-96-5p   6877    8207.33
Control     7222.67 9238.5
```

My melted data:

```
        ID        variable   value
1       mir-21-3p      24h 7122.67
2     mir-135b-5p      24h 7093.00
3      mir-584-5p      24h 7227.33
4        mir-7974      24h 7369.67
5      mir-183-3p      24h 7493.00
6      mir-182-5p      24h 7471.00

ggplot(d.m, aes(variable,value)) + geom_point(stat="identity") + facet_grid(~ID)
```

Comment: Why is reformatting the input table not a viable solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Repeat values to multiple plots when faceting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813610/repeat-values-to-multiple-plots-when-faceting)